# JavaScript error: undefined, line 492: Component returned failure code:

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I am new to selenium, and getting this below error.

Selenium 3.4.0 Firefox browser 47.0.2 geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64

Please help on this, Thanks in advance. :)

Below is the test code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

    /*   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
       capabilities.setCapability("marionette", false); // true getting : AddonManager is not initialized
       WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities); */

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    vURL = "http://www.facebook.com";
    driver.navigate().to(vURL);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='day']")).sendKeys("9");
    driver.quit();
```

Error:

> JavaScript error: undefined, line 492: Component returned failure
>   code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIPrefBranch.getCharPref]
>   JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 2484:
>   NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized Oct 11, 2017
>   3:43:19 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

Comment: You are commented the code 

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

Comment: Your FF version is really old. Update FF, Selenium, and the drivers to the newest versions and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You are commented the code

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

then how driver is instantiate

use this it is working

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(); 
    String vURL = "http://www.facebook.com";
    driver.navigate().to(vURL);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='day']")).sendKeys("9");
    driver.quit();
```

Comment: You change the path of geckodriver

Comment: tried above but not working : JavaScript error: undefined, line 492: Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIPrefBranch.getCharPref]
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 2484: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized
Oct 11, 2017 5:49:45 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
1507724385576 geckodriver INFO Listening on 127.0.0.1:26330
1507724386078 geckodriver::marionette INFOStarting browser \\?\C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]

Comment: Try it with chrome

Comment: Which version of selenium and firefox you are using

Comment: Selenium 3.4.0 Firefox browser 47.0.2 geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64

Comment: Update the broser to 50 or 51 and geckdriver too

Comment: that will work with selenium 3.4.0 or I need to update selenium too